How to wrap any Error into custom error type in Rust
Let's say I want to make a MyError type into which I could put an arbitrary error - I want to return my error type in the Result of my trait's methods in order to abstract from implementation details. I want to be able to use the question operator with automatic error type conversion when writing the implementation of these methods, rather than manually calling map_err:
use derive_more::Display;
use thiserror::Error;

#[derive(Error, Debug, Display)]
pub struct MyError(#[source] Box<dyn std::error::Error>);

impl<T: std::error::Error> From<T> for MyError {
    fn from(value: T) -> Self {
        Self(Box::new(value))
    }
}

This approach produces a compilation error:
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `From<MyError>` for type `MyError`
 --> src\mod.rs:9:1
  |
9 | impl<T: std::error::Error> From<T> for MyError {
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: conflicting implementation in crate `core`:
          - impl<T> From<T> for T;

As I understand it, the problem is that MyError itself implements the Error trait and it creates something like recursion.
Is it possible to fix this issue?

Does it have to be an arbitrary error type? thiserror is mostly designed to support non-arbitrary error types; anyhow is its more flexible cousin.

If you're doing the Box<dyn Error> dance, you're probably reinventing anyhow::Error, which I recommend for several good qualities, including using a narrow pointer to ensure that results don't get too wide. anyhow::Error solves the issue you're having by simply not implementing the Error trait. That sounds extreme, but it also provides a type-erased impl that does, which allows you to convert it to dyn Error. See here for more details.

The thiserror crate wasn't really designed for this. But if you're okay with listing each wrapped error type, you can use its #[from] attribute to generate From implementations for you:
#[derive(Error, Debug, Display)]
pub enum MyError {
    IOError(#[from] std::io::Error),
}

fn frobnicate() -> Result<(), MyError> {
    std::fs::read("foo")?;
    Ok(())
}

It's only a single line per error type, and most libraries only expose a single error type, so the amount of boilerplate is quite small.
